# Here strings in ksh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ksh

What is wrong with the script below?

```
#!/bin/bash
a="\\\"P1\\\"\\\"P2\\\"\\\"P3\\\"\\\"P4\\\"\\\"P5\\\""
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\\\\\\\""} {$10="";NF-=2}1' <<< "$a"
```

Output:

```
\\\"P1\\\"\\\"P2\\\"\\\"P3\\\"\\\"P4\\\"
```

It works in `bash` but I tested in `ksh` and got the following error message:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
a="\\\"P1\\\"\\\"P2\\\"\\\"P3\\\"\\\"P4\\\"\\\"P5\\\""
b=$(awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\\\\\\\""} {$10="";NF-=2}1' <<< "$a")
 .sh: syntax error: `< ' unexpected
```

I got problems in ksh shell, but this works

```
b=` echo $a | sed -e 's/\\\\"[^"]*\\\\"$//g' `
```

Comment: There are far too many backslashes in that code!  It is unreadable.

Answer (score 2):

The here string syntax `<<<` is a `bash` feature not supported by `ksh`. Just change your command to:

```
b=$(echo "$a" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\\\\\\\""} {$10="";NF-=2}1')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use here docs instead:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\\\\\\\""} {$10="";NF-=2}1' <<EOD
$a
EOD
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be using `ksh88` or some `ksh` clone.

The posted code works fine with a current `ksh` release, and by current I mean newer than `ksh93m+` released in 2002.